# ksoap2-android serialize an empty array

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I want to create an object Group with an empty list inside it using ksoap2. I managed to do this on stand alone application using webservice method but, using android gives me an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: []` My question, is there a walkaround to this error?

Here is my `WSDL` xml:

```
<xs:complexType name="createGroup">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="new-group-object" type="tns:group" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="group">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="groupId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="groupName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="users" type="tns:user" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="user">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="latitude" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="longitude" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="userAge" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="userId" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and my android client method:

```
public void createGroupServ(String groupName) 
{
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "createGroup");
    SoapObject soapGroup = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "group");

    Group gr = new Group();
    gr.setGroupName(groupName);
    gr.setUsers(new ArrayList<User>());
    request.addProperty("new-group-object", gr);

    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
      ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement KvmSerializable interface for group and user. Read the articles:
[java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: MyClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148600/java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-serialize-myclass)

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2594

I recommend to upgrade to last version of ksoap because may be you'll have to use:
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html
for your double data types