# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: MyClass

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I am trying to consume a web service through my android app by making a call to a function which expects a class object as an input parameter. But while making a call i'm getting an  error java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: MyClass

I have tried the following solutions but this did not help :
[KSOAP2 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907434/ksoap2-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-serialize)

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=141

Code: 
                        SoapObject request = helperLogin();

```
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER10);

        envelope.dotNet = false;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "L1UserProfileRowDTO", L1UserProfileRowDTO.class);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "L1UserRowDTO", L1UserRowDTO.class);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        TextView ACTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

the last line throws exception.

My class implements serializable interface and also has a default constructor.
Please help.

Comment: are L1UserProfileRowDTO and L1UserRowDTO  serializable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem:

```
public class L1UserProfileRowDTO extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable
```

and also over ride the following functions:

```
@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.size();
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg2.name = "string";
    arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.add(arg1.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing `Serializable` in `MyClass`. It goes like this -

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
   // Constructor

   // Properties

   // Methods
}
```

Comment: @blackbelt: yes both classes implement serializable interface